# PowerShell foreach all files and calculate each md5 value

Tags: powershell

I Have a script to get all html files in a folder,i want to get all md5 values,here's the code:

```
$Allfiles=get-childItem("*html")
Foreavch-object($Mfile in $Allfiles)
{
    $Md5=calMd5($Mfile)

    If($HashQueue.contains($Mfile))
    {
        Continue 
    }
    Else 
    {Enqueue()}

}
```

i Can't get the file correctly, how to foreach every file in a dir?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do. What do you mean by "get" the files? Get the content into strings, or iterate over objects representing the files? How does calMd5 work? Does it take a string argument (as I'd expect), or can it operate on FileInfo objects? What is $HashQueue - what's in it, how is it populated? What is Enqueue()? That's not a native function. There's an Enqueue method that would be invoked on a Queue object and requires an argument. If you're trying to create a queue, what for? In what way do you want to "get" the md5 values - what kind of results do you want?

Comment: FYI http://pscx.codeplex.com has a Get-Hash command e.g. `Get-ChildItem *.html | Get-Hash | Foreach {if (!$HashQueue.Contains($_.Hash)) { $Enqueue($_.Path) }}`.  BTW your script above doesn't show what you do with the MD5 value.

Comment: Ah, okay...it helps a lot to specify when one's code is based on an extension that's not part of the standard distribution. And, of course, to be clear and specific about what the goal is. "Get all md5 values" is very broad and open to interpretation. The most important question in my comment above is the last one - what kind of output or results do you want to end up with?

Comment: @AdiInbar I'm not disagreeing anything you've said in your comments.  Just pointing out "as a comment" that FYI, there's a handy Get-Hash command available in PSCX.  BTW in PowerShell V4, Get-FileHash is now a built-in command.

Comment: @KeithHill My comment was addressed to Scott, after you pointed out that he was using an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses are never used when calling a function or cmdlet in PowerShell.

You also have a typo in your `foreach-object` (note the `v` in your code).

What is `calMd5` expecting as a parameter? A file name? Full path to the file? An object? Same questions for what you're putting into `$HashQueue`.

Assuming `calMd5` can take the path to the file and that's what you're putting into `$HashQueue`:

```
$Allfiles = get-childItem -filter *html
Foreach-object($Mfile in $Allfiles)
{
    $Md5 = calMd5 $Mfile.FullName

    If(!$HashQueue.contains($Mfile.FullName))
    {
        Enqueue()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you're trying to do, but I'm going to infer that you want something like this:

```
$MD5Hashes = @{}
Get-ChildItem *.html | %{
  $MD5Hashes.Add($_.Name, (calMd5 Get-Content $_ | Out-String)
}
```

This code creates a hashtable of the MD5 hashes of the files, keyed on the filenames, assuming that the **calMd5** function takes a string argument. You'd look up the MD5 hash for a file like this: `$MD5Hashes.'filename'`.  Or if you have the filename in a variable, like this: `$MD5Hashes."$filename"`.

A few notes:

- It's superfluous to assign the results of **Get-ChildItem** to a variable and iterate over it with **Foreach-Object**. Just pipe the results to a **Foreach-Object** block (**%{}** is shorthand for **Foreach-Object**). Object pipelines are one of the central features of PowerShell design. You'll learn to love 'em.
- Although `Get-ChildItem("*html")` *will* work, it does so indirectly and incidentally. As alroc said, you don't use parentheses to pass arguments to a PowerShell cmdlet or function (though you *do* use them to pass arguments to methods). In most contexts, parentheses are an expression evaluation operator. The reason this command works is that `("*html")` evaluates to the string `*html`, which is then passed as an argument to **Get-ChildItem**. In this case, the parentheses are superfluous, but in many cases you'll run into trouble enclosing arguments in parentheses, unless you *intend* for the argument to be the result of an expression rather than the contents of the parentheses verbatim.
- If **$HashQueue** is a queue object and you want to add the MD5 values to this queue, you'd do this:

  `$HashQueue.Enqueue((calMd5 Get-Content $_ | Out-String))`

  However, I'm presuming that's not what you want to do, because it doesn't make sense to me to enqueue the MD5 hashes onto the end of a queue that already contains FileInfo objects representing the files (implied by `If($HashQueue.contains($Mfile))`).

If this is not what you want to do, please clarify. See the questions in my comment, and please be as specific as possible.